# Getting the Max In Different Years

Tags: ms-access

I am pulling together a table of training data for employees who took various training courses between 2010 and 2013. I am getting the counts by course. Some training an employee can accidentally register for multiple times in one year, I just need the individual employee counts. Some training however is required to be taken each year or every other year, I am trying to get the max date for each training completed for each year, so in case someone did take a course one year and then again a year later, both of them are counted. The code I have so far is,

```
SELECT [Training_GEMS].JOB_CLS_CD_DSC_TE, [Training_GEMS].TNG_NA, [Training_GEMS].TNG_SYS_NR, [Training_GEMS].JOB_CLS_CD, sum(iif(Max_Date BETWEEN #1/1/2010# AND #12/31/2010#,1,0)) AS 2010, sum(iif(Max_Date BETWEEN #1/1/2011# AND #12/31/2011#,1,0)) AS 2011, sum(iif(Max_Date BETWEEN #1/1/2012# AND #12/31/2012#,1,0)) AS 2012, sum(iif(Max_Date BETWEEN #1/1/2013# AND #12/31/2013#,1,0)) AS 2013
FROM Training_GEMS
GROUP BY [Training_GEMS].JOB_CLS_CD_DSC_TE, [Training_GEMS].TNG_NA, [Training_GEMS].TNG_SYS_NR, [Training_GEMS].JOB_CLS_CD;
```

I have the SUM IIFs setup, I am just trying to get the max for each year.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add the following four lines (after adding comma to last SUM ... 2013 field)

```
     Max(Iif(max_date BETWEEN #1 / 1 / 2010 # 
                        AND #12 / 31 / 2010 # , max_date, null))   AS 2010max,
     Max(Iif(max_date BETWEEN #1 / 1 / 2011 # 
                        AND #12 / 31 / 2011 # , max_date, null))   AS 2011max,
     Max(Iif(max_date BETWEEN #1 / 1 / 2012 # 
                        AND #12 / 31 / 2012 # , max_date, null))   AS 2012max,
     Max(Iif(max_date BETWEEN #1 / 1 / 2013 # 
                        AND #12 / 31 / 2013 # , max_date, null))   AS 2013max
```

Answer (score 0):

Something like this may require two steps.  The first would be as you describe in eliminating any people that took a course more than once in a year.

```
Select UserID, Year(CourseDate) as CourseYear, Course, Max(CourseDate) as CourseDate
From Training_Gems
Group by Year(CourseDate), UserID, Course;
```

You can get the year from a date using the Year() function without having to create a new column for each year with an IIF.

Once you have your first results you can use them in a second sub-query like so.

```
select Count(Course), Course From
(Select UserID, Year(CourseDate) as CourseYear, Course, Max(CourseDate) as CourseDate
From Training_Gems
Group by Year(CourseDate), UserID, Course) as t1
Group By Course;
```